# How to update numericInput from two different sources in R?

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny, shiny-server, numeric-input

I'm trying to build an easy Shiny Application where  I can take up the current heating curve from a heating system in a building and visualize it in a plot. This happens manually with 4 numericInput Fields (2 values for x-coordinates and 2 values for y-coordinates).

With aditionally two different questions (in this Case handled with radioButtons) I should get a suggestion for a new, current heating curve, where I can conduct some changes on my heating system. The new values (which are calculated from the first numericInputs and the radioButtons) should be displayed in 4 addition numericInput Fields (This is already working with updateNumericInput() and observeEvent()).

Furthermore, when the first suggestion is displayed after i put the information (radioButtons), I want to be able to adjust the new curve with the 4 numericinputs in the second part. This is my current challenge where I'm struggeling with. These Fields are blocked after I defined my Information (radioButtons).

Below I've listed my Code.

Thanks for help!

I've also tried to work with a matrix to calculate each different option in advance and only draw the Line (segment(...)) with reference to the correct matrix row. Also I've tried to work without the observeEvent function to overwrite the numericInput Variable but didn't work either.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jsCode <- 'shinyjs.winprint = function(){
window.print();
}'

ui <- fluidPage(

    #Application title
    titlePanel(title = "Heatingcurve"),

    sidebarLayout(
      #User Input            
      sidebarPanel(width = 3,
                   #user Data
                   textInput("ProjName", "project name"),
                   textInput("ProjNr", "Project nr."),
                   dateInput("date", "date", value = NULL),
                   textInput("heating group", "heatinggroup"),
                   textInput("autor", "autor"),

                   #horizontal line
                   tags$hr(style="border-color: darkgrey;"), 

                   #Include numeric Input field (current numbers)
                   h3(tags$b("Heating numbers observed")),  
                   tags$div(h4("OT [\u00B0C]", align = "center"), numericInput("x11", "x11", value = -10),
                            numericInput("x21", "x21", value = 25), style="display:inline-block"),
                   tags$div(h4("FT [\u00B0C]", align = "center"), numericInput("y11", "y11", value = 65),
                            numericInput("y21", "y21", value = 45), style="display:inline-block"),

                   #horizontal line
                   tags$hr(style="border-color: darkgrey;"), 

                   #Include numeric Input field (calculated numbrs, adjustable numbers)
                   h3(tags$b("new adjusted heating numbers (calculated or adjusted)"),
                   tags$div(h4("OT [\u00B0C]", align = "center"), numericInput("x12", "x12", value = 0),
                            numericInput("x22", "x22", value = 0), style="display:inline-block"),
                   tags$div(h4("FT [\u00B0C]", align = "center"), numericInput("y12", "y12", value = 0),
                            numericInput("y22", "y22", value = 0), style="display:inline-block")                                      
      )),

      mainPanel(

        tags$br(),

        radioButtons("radio1", 
                     "What is the feeling of comfort in the reference room like in warm weather?", 
                     choices = c("too cold"= 1, "good" = 2, "too hot" = 3),
                     selected = 0, inline = TRUE),


        radioButtons("radio2", 
                     "What is the feeling of comfort in the reference room like in cold weather?", 
                     choices = c("too cold"= 1, "good" = 2, "too hot" = 3),
                     selected = 0, inline = TRUE),

        plotOutput("plot1"),

        #Notes
        textAreaInput("notes", "Notes", width = "1200px", height = "300px"), 

        #Print Button 
        useShinyjs(),
        extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
        actionButton("print", "Print",
                     style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4") 
      )          
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


      #update numericinput (Part2)
      upDateFunction <- function(x0, x1, y0, y1) {

        observeEvent(input$x12, {
          updateNumericInput(session, "x12", value = x0)
        })

        observeEvent(input$x22, {
          updateNumericInput(session, "x22", value = x1)
        })  

        observeEvent(input$y12, {
          updateNumericInput(session, "y12", value = y0)
        })  

        observeEvent(input$y22, {
          updateNumericInput(session, "y22", value = y1)
        })

        segments(x0, y0, x1, y1, col = "red", lwd = 3)
      }    


      #create plot 
      output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

        plot(1, type="n",xlab = "Outsidetemperature [\u00B0C]", ylab="Flowtemperature [\u00B0C]", 
             xlim=c(-15, 30), ylim=c(15, 80), panel.first = grid(col = "gray", lwd = 1.5))


        #create black solid line (for design)
        segments(x0 = 0, y0 = 17, x1 = 0, y1 = 90, col = "black", lwd = 1)

        #create black solid line (for design)
        segments(x0 = -40, y0 = 20, x1 = 50, y1 = 20, col = "black", lwd = 1)

        #create blue heating curve
        segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21, col = "blue", lwd = 3)


        #conditions (radioButtons)
        if (length(input$radio1) == 0 & length(input$radio2) == 0) {
          segments(x0 = 0, y0 = 20, x1 = 0, y1 = 90, col = "black", lwd = 1)
        }

        else if (length(input$radio1) != 0 & length(input$radio2) == 0) {
          segments(x0 = 0, y0 = 20, x1 = 0, y1 = 90, col = "black", lwd = 1)
        }

        else if (length(input$radio1) == 0 & length(input$radio2) != 0) {
          segments(x0 = 0, y0 = 20, x1 = 0, y1 = 90, col = "black", lwd = 1)
        }

        else if (input$radio1 == 0 & input$radio2 == 0) {
          #segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 + 3, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21 + 3, col = "red", lwd = 3)
          upDateFunction(x0 = input$x12, y0 = input$y12, x1 = input$x22, y1 = input$y22)
        }

        else if (input$radio1 == 1 & input$radio2 == 1) {
          #segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 + 3, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21 + 3, col = "red", lwd = 3)
          upDateFunction(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 + 3, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21 + 3)
          #upDateFunction(x0 = input$x12, y0 = input$y12, x1 = input$x22, y1 = input$y22)
        }

        else if (input$radio1 == 1 & input$radio2 == 2) {
          #segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21* 5/4, col = "red", lwd = 3)
          upDateFunction(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21 * 5/4)
        }

        else if (input$radio1 == 1 & input$radio2 == 3) {
          #segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 * (0.9), x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21 / 0.9, col = "red", lwd = 3)
          upDateFunction(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 * (0.9), x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21 / 0.9)
        }

        else if (input$radio1 == 2 & input$radio2 == 1) {
          #segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 * 5/4, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21, col = "red", lwd = 3)
          upDateFunction(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 * 5/4, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21)
        }

        else if (input$radio1 == 2 & input$radio2 == 2) {
          #segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21, col = "red", lwd = 3)
          upDateFunction(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21)
        }

        else if (input$radio1 == 2 & input$radio2 == 3) {
          #segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 * 4/5, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21, col = "red", lwd = 3)
          upDateFunction(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 * 4/5, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21)
        }

        else if (input$radio1 == 3 & input$radio2 == 1) {
          #segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 * (2/1)/1.5, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21 * (1/2/1), col = "red", lwd = 3)
          upDateFunction(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 * (2/1)/1.5, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21 * (1/2/1))
        }

        else if (input$radio1 == 3 & input$radio2 == 2) {
          #segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 , x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21 * 2/3, col = "red", lwd = 3)
          upDateFunction(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 , x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21 * 2/3)
        }

        else if (input$radio1 == 3 & input$radio2 == 3) {
          #segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 - 3, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21 - 3, col = "red", lwd = 3)
          upDateFunction(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 - 3, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21 - 3)
        }

        legend("topright", legend=c("Heating numbers observed", "new adjusted heating numbers (calculated or adjusted)"), col = c("blue", "red"), lty = 1:1, cex = 1)                    
      })       
    }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The code seems to be missing a `library(shinyjs)` and also has an undefined `jsCode` object: it's not runnable at the moment. I think your question would also benefit from having a more minimal example to work with.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila Indeed, I missed some code due to copying into one file, what you already mentioned. I added the following at the top of the script:  `library(shinyjs)`  `jsCode <- 'shinyjs.winprint = function(){ window.print(); }'` . My main issue is that I don't see trough the different updates between the inputs in the code.  Does the script now run on your machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jsCode <- 'shinyjs.winprint = function(){
window.print();
}'

ui <- fluidPage(

  #Application title
  titlePanel(title = "Heatingcurve"),

  sidebarLayout(
    #User Input            
    sidebarPanel(width = 3,
                 #user Data
                 textInput("ProjName", "project name"),
                 textInput("ProjNr", "Project nr."),
                 dateInput("date", "date", value = NULL),
                 textInput("heating group", "heatinggroup"),
                 textInput("autor", "autor"),

                 #horizontal line
                 tags$hr(style="border-color: darkgrey;"), 

                 #Include numeric Input field (current numbers)
                 h3(tags$b("Heating numbers observed")),  
                 tags$div(h4("OT [\u00B0C]", align = "center"), numericInput("x11", "x11", value = -10),
                          numericInput("x21", "x21", value = 25), style="display:inline-block"),
                 tags$div(h4("FT [\u00B0C]", align = "center"), numericInput("y11", "y11", value = 65),
                          numericInput("y21", "y21", value = 45), style="display:inline-block"),

                 #horizontal line
                 tags$hr(style="border-color: darkgrey;"), 

                 #Include numeric Input field (calculated numbrs, adjustable numbers)
                 h3(tags$b("new adjusted heating numbers (calculated or adjusted)"),
                    tags$div(h4("OT [\u00B0C]", align = "center"), numericInput("x12", "x12", value = 0),
                             numericInput("x22", "x22", value = 0), style="display:inline-block"),
                    tags$div(h4("FT [\u00B0C]", align = "center"), numericInput("y12", "y12", value = 0),
                             numericInput("y22", "y22", value = 0), style="display:inline-block")                                      
                 )),

    mainPanel(

      tags$br(),

      radioButtons("radio1", 
                   "What is the feeling of comfort in the reference room like in warm weather?", 
                   choices = c("adjust manually" = 0, "too cold"= 1, "good" = 2, "too hot" = 3),
                   selected = 0, inline = TRUE),


      radioButtons("radio2", 
                   "What is the feeling of comfort in the reference room like in cold weather?", 
                   choices = c("adjust manually" = 0, "too cold"= 1, "good" = 2, "too hot" = 3),
                   selected = 0, inline = TRUE),

      plotOutput("plot1"),

      #Notes
      textAreaInput("notes", "Notes", width = "1200px", height = "300px"), 

      #Print Button 
      useShinyjs(),
      extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
      actionButton("print", "Print",
                   style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4") 
    )          
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {


  #update numericinput (Part2)
  reac1 <- reactiveValues()
  reac2 <- reactiveValues()
  reac3 <- reactiveValues()
  reac4 <- reactiveValues()

  observeEvent(input$x11,{
    reac1$numeric <- input$x11
  })
  observe({
    req(reac1$numeric)
    updateNumericInput(session, "x12", value = reac1$numeric)
  })



  observeEvent(input$x21, {
    reac2$numeric <- input$x21
  })
  observe({
    req(reac2$numeric)
    updateNumericInput(session, "x22", value = reac2$numeric)
  })



  observeEvent(input$y11, {
    reac3$numeric <- input$y11
  })
  observe({
    req(reac3$numeric)
    updateNumericInput(session, "y12", value = reac3$numeric)
  })



  observeEvent(input$y21, {
    reac4$numeric <- input$y21
  })
  observe({
    req(reac4$numeric)
    updateNumericInput(session, "y22", value = reac4$numeric)
  })   


  #create plot 
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    plot(1, type="n",xlab = "Outsidetemperature [\u00B0C]", ylab="Flowtemperature [\u00B0C]", 
         xlim=c(-15, 30), ylim=c(15, 80), panel.first = grid(col = "gray", lwd = 1.5))


    #create black solid line (for design)
    segments(x0 = 0, y0 = 17, x1 = 0, y1 = 90, col = "black", lwd = 1)

    #create black solid line (for design)
    segments(x0 = -40, y0 = 20, x1 = 50, y1 = 20, col = "black", lwd = 1)

    #create blue heating curve
    segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21, col = "blue", lwd = 3)


    #conditions (radioButtons)
    if (length(input$radio1) == 0 & length(input$radio2) == 0) {
      segments(x0 = 0, y0 = 20, x1 = 0, y1 = 90, col = "black", lwd = 1)
    }

    else if (length(input$radio1) != 0 & length(input$radio2) == 0) {
      segments(x0 = 0, y0 = 20, x1 = 0, y1 = 90, col = "black", lwd = 1)
    }

    else if (length(input$radio1) == 0 & length(input$radio2) != 0) {
      segments(x0 = 0, y0 = 20, x1 = 0, y1 = 90, col = "black", lwd = 1)
    }

    else if (input$radio1 == 0 & input$radio2 == 0) {
      segments(x0 = input$x12, y0 = input$y12, x1 = input$x22, y1 = input$y22, col = "red", lwd = 3)
    }





    else if (input$radio1 == 1 & input$radio2 == 1) {
      segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 + 3, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21 + 3, col = "red", lwd = 3)

    }

    else if (input$radio1 == 1 & input$radio2 == 2) {
      segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21* 5/4, col = "red", lwd = 3)

    }

    else if (input$radio1 == 1 & input$radio2 == 3) {
      segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 * (0.9), x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21 / 0.9, col = "red", lwd = 3)
    }

    else if (input$radio1 == 2 & input$radio2 == 1) {
      segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 * 5/4, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21, col = "red", lwd = 3)
    }

    else if (input$radio1 == 2 & input$radio2 == 2) {
      segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21, col = "red", lwd = 3)
    }

    else if (input$radio1 == 2 & input$radio2 == 3) {
      segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 * 4/5, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21, col = "red", lwd = 3)
    }

    else if (input$radio1 == 3 & input$radio2 == 1) {
      segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 * (2/1)/1.5, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21 * (1/2/1), col = "red", lwd = 3)
    }

    else if (input$radio1 == 3 & input$radio2 == 2) {
      segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 , x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21 * 2/3, col = "red", lwd = 3)
    }

    else if (input$radio1 == 3 & input$radio2 == 3) {
      segments(x0 = input$x11, y0 = input$y11 - 3, x1 = input$x21, y1 = input$y21 - 3, col = "red", lwd = 3)
    }

    legend("topright", legend=c("Heating numbers observed", "new adjusted heating numbers (calculated or adjusted)"), col = c("blue", "red"), lty = 1:1, cex = 1)                    
  })       
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to update reactive values on every change and use `updateNumericInput` then based on the reactive value only.

Here is an easy example on how to use two buttons to update the same `numericInput`

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
        mainPanel(
            numericInput("numericInput", "Numeric Input", min = 0, max = 200, value = 50),
            actionButton("button1", "Updatebutton 1"),
            actionButton("button2", "Updatebutton 2")
        )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    reac <- reactiveValues()

    observeEvent(input$button1, {
        reac$numeric <- round(runif(1, 0, 100))
    })
    observeEvent(input$button2, {
        reac$numeric <- round(runif(1, 100, 200))
    })
    observe({
        req(reac$numeric)
        updateNumericInput(session, "numericInput", value = reac$numeric)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank's for your input! I could implement and modify your example for my application - it works now. Below I've posted my script.